# Append input element to form fieldset using vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

As the header describes, I would like to append input elements to some fieldset in my form.
I build a staged form with 3 fieldsets which appear only when "Next" button is clicked.

Now in fieldset number 3 I want to input elements based on keys I'm extracting from a external json object.

**Data:**

```
data: () => ({
    
        currentPage: 0,
        brand: '',
        platform: '',
        affiliate: '',
        fieldsetThree: document.getElementById("fieldset3"),
}),
```

**Fieldset(only appears when currentPage value is 2):**

```
<div v-if="currentPage === 2">
  <fieldset id="fieldset3">
    <h2 class="fs-title">API Credentials</h2>
    <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Step 3- Add any parameter for the integration</h3>
  </fieldset>
  </div>
```

**Function to append the input fields after Stage 2 is done:**

```
 appendFields() {
          let check = json[this.platform];

          console.log(this.fieldsetThree);
          for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(check)) {

            let inputfield = document.createElement("input");
            this.inputfield.setAttribute("type", "text");
            this.inputfield.setAttribute("name",`${key}`);
            this.inputfield.setAttribute("placeholder",`${key}`);
            console.log("Input FIeld \n", this.inputfield)
            this.fieldsetThree.appendChild(this.inputfield);
          }
          //Build it before.
        },
```

The goal is to create an input field for every key in the JSON, I will add the json format for example:

```
"exmaple": {
                "Username": "",
                "Password": "",
                "AffiliateID": "",
                "GI": "",
                "CI": "",
                "freeTextArea": ""
            },
```

FUll code(without Template):

```
export default {
    data: () => ({
        
            currentPage: 0,
            brand: '',
            platform: '',
            affiliate: '',

    }),
    computed: {
      platformData: function () {
          return json[this.platform];
      }
    },
    methods: {
        isNextClicked() {
            var nextStage = this.currentPage;
            this.currentPage++;
            console.log("CurrentPage =>", this.currentPage);
            $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(nextStage)).addClass("active");
            return this.currentPage;
        },
        isPreviousClicked() {

            this.currentPage--;
            var previousStage = this.currentPage;
            console.log("CurrentPage at decrease =>", this.currentPage);
            $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(previousStage)).removeClass("active");
            return this.currentPage;
        },
        appendFields() {
          // let check = json[this.platform];
          // console.log(this.fieldsetThree);
          // for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(check)) {
          //
          //   let inputfield = document.createElement("input");
          //   this.inputfield.setAttribute("type", "text");
          //   this.inputfield.setAttribute("name",`${key}`);
          //   this.inputfield.setAttribute("placeholder",`${key}`);
          //   console.log("Input FIeld \n", this.inputfield)
          //   this.fieldsetThree.appendChild(this.inputfield);
          // }
          //Build it before.
        },
        nextPlusappend() {
            //this.appendFields();
            this.isNextClicked();

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you work out the structure you want to keep your data, then you don't need to mess with DOM elements: just add the JSON to the `data()` & let Vue do its thing.

So, if you take the JSON data structure as the base for the form fields & fieldsets, then you can just add it to the data item holding the form input fields:

```js
const example = {
  "Username": "",
  "Password": "",
  "AffiliateID": "",
  "GI": "",
  "CI": "",
  "freeTextArea": ""
}

Vue.component("formFieldset", {
  props: ["fields"],
  methods: {
    handleInput(val, key) {
      this.$emit("update:fields", { key, val })
    },
  },
  template: `
    <div>
      <label
        v-for="(val, key) in fields"
        :key="key"
      >
        {{ key }}: 
        <input
          type="text"
          :placeholder="key"
          @input="(e) => handleInput(e.target.value, key)"
        />
      </label>
      <hr>
    </div>
  `
})

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      fieldsets: [
        {
          field1_1: "",
          field1_2: "",
        },
        {
          field2_1: "",
          field2_2: "",
        },
      ],
    }
  },
  // just to add the items later to the data():
  mounted() {
    this.fieldsets.push(example)
  },
  methods: {
    handleUpdateFields({ key, val, idx }) {
      this.fieldsets[idx][key] = val
    },
  },
  template: `
    <div>
      Putting out the data():<br />
      {{ fieldsets }}
      <hr>
      <form>
        <form-fieldset
          v-for="(fieldset, i) in fieldsets"
          :key="i"
          :fields="fieldset"
          @update:fields="(e) => handleUpdateFields({...e, idx: i})"
        />
      </form>
    </div>
  `
})
```

```css
label {
  display: block;
  padding: 8px 16px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Actually this is more complicated to me to understand what you did here, Every object inside the json have unique fields so i need it to be dynamic per object, meaning that not every object have "Username" or "Password". I', very sorry but I'm new to vue and I didnt understand what you did here

Comment: I edited the question with the structure of export () and to mention, the Form is a different component i created, I'm not building my app inside app.vue. all of the code above is written inside Form.vue